# Generating a date list of the next 90 days

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to cretae an array of dates for the next 90 days, filtered down to only show specific days. So for example I would like a list of all the dates that are a tuesdayin the next 90 days.

So far I have tried to simply generate an array with ALL of the dates for the next 90 days, but it's not working. here's what I have: ​

```
var date = new Date();
var chckDates = [];
for (i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    chckDates.push(dmy);
}
console.log(chckDates);
```

That array ends up increment by n+1 each time by the looks of it. So for example it adds 1 day, then it adds 1 day again and then 2 days, then 3... So the dates I get go: 11th, 12th, 14th, 17th etc etc.

My two questions are:

1. How do I simply get it to return a straightforward list of all upcoming dates for the next 90 days.
2. How do I then filter that array down to exclude all *except* any Tuesdays?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _straightforward list_ ?

Comment: just add 1 each loop

Comment: Why create 90 dates then filter out 86% of them? Just start on a Tuesday (next, previous, closest, whatever) and add 7 days repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var chckDates = [];
for (i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear()
    chckDates.push(dmy);
}
console.log(chckDates);
```

You were actually increasing the date by 1 day, then adding i to that already incremented date. i is exponential, hence the exponential increase in days.

What I mean is, previously you were doing

date = date + 1 + i, where i was 1, 2, 3, 4. So each iteration date was increasing by one anyway, then adding i. Just the +1 is fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/bdrnkkn9/2/

To exclude all but Tuesdays

```
var date = new Date();
var chckDates = [];
for (i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    if(date.getDay() == 2) { // I think 2 is Tuesday, you'll have to double check this. 
        var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear()
        chckDates.push(dmy);
    }
}
console.log(chckDates);
```

Comment: Not exponential increase, geometric. ;-) Also, once you get to the first Tuesday, you can just add 7 days to get to the next one (yes, 2 is Tuesday).

Comment: Correct, you could add 7 days @robG, but his question said he wanted to filter the array down, not create one with just Tuesdays. I've just realised my answer does neither though. The way he requested would require two for loops, yours would be simpler.

Comment: Apply the same logic to the filter: once a Tuesday is found, get every 7th index from then on (assumes it's a contiguous array of dates). But I just assumed that the OP had chosen an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: He had, but I was assuming he needed the array of dates which he then wanted to filter down for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Tuesdays, you can generate just Tuesday dates. There should be sufficient documentation and comments in the function below for you to follow. Let me know if you need more:

```js
/*  Return an array of date strings of Tuesdays from startDate up to 
**  startDate + bound. If the start date is a Tuesday, it's not included
**
**  @param {number} bound   - number of days from startDate to collect Tuesdays
**  @param {Date} startDate - optional, the date to start from
**  @returns {Array}        - array of ISO 8601 date strings (y-m-d)
*/
function getTuesdays(bound, startDate) {
  var dates = [];
  
  // Copy start date or create a new date if not provided
  startDate = startDate? new Date(+startDate) : new Date();
  
  // Work out days to next Tuesday
  var shift = (9 - startDate.getDay())%7 || 7;
  
  // Adjust bound for shift
  bound -= shift;
  
  // Adjust startDate for shift
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + shift);
  
  // Generate dates, increment date and decrement bound
  while (bound >= 0) {
    dates.push(toLocalISODate(startDate));
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);
    bound -= 7;
  }
  return dates;
}

function toLocalISODate(d) {
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0'+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

// Get Tuesdays in the next 18 days
document.write(getTuesdays(18).join('<br>'));
```